# Crop image enclosed in a 4 sided (not rectangle) polygon

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to crop image portion that is enclosed inside a random polygon (4 sided but not rectangle). Just wanted to know which method to follow not the code.

Comment: snapshot the polygon view.

Comment: Get the `CGRect` equivalent of that quadrilateral: Minimum rectangle that "includes" the polygon. Then crop. Is the way of finding that `CGRect` your issue? You could also set transparent the part of the image outside the area of the polygon.

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri: I want to crop the area that is inside the polygon. The polygon can change its dimensions dynamically

Comment: @Larme: By selecting the Minimum Rectangle i wont get exact image that is enclosed in polygon

Comment: You have to apply a mask after then ! How is cretaed your polygon?

Comment: I am creating a polygon by using  bezier path (lines) between 4 points

Answer (score 6):

### You can do this easily in Core Graphics.

You just need to create a new image context, add the path to the context, then crop the context to the path. You can then draw your image in this and get out a cropped image.

```
-(UIImage*) cropImage:(UIImage*)image withPath:(UIBezierPath*)path { // where the UIBezierPath is defined in the UIKit coordinate system (0,0) is top left

    CGRect r = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path.CGPath); // the rect to draw our image in (minimum rect that the path occupies).

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, NO, image.scale); // begin image context, with transparency & the scale of the image.
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -r.origin.x, -r.origin.y); // translate context so that when we add the path, it starts at (0,0).

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath); // add path.
    CGContextClip(ctx); // clip any future drawing to the path region.

    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, image.size}]; // draw image

    UIImage* i = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // get image from context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); // clean up and finish context

    return i; // return image
}
```

For example, if we take a screenshot of your question (I couldn't find any other images lying about!)

[image]

and use the following code....

```
UIImage* i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];

UIBezierPath* p = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[p moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(1500, 500)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(500, 1200)];

UIImage* i1 = [self cropImage:i withPath:p];
```

This would be the output...

[image]

**You could even add this to a `UIImage` category if you're going to be cropping images regularly.**

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift 3.

I noticed that a lot of the implementations out there seem to want the background to be white or transparent, and I really needed just wanted the background color to be black.

```
extension UIImage {

    func crop(withPath: UIBezierPath, andColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let r: CGRect = withPath.cgPath.boundingBox
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, false, self.scale)
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            context.setFillColor(andColor.cgColor)
            context.fill(rect)
            context.translateBy(x: -r.origin.x, y: -r.origin.y)
            context.addPath(withPath.cgPath)
            context.clip()
        }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
            return UIImage()
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }

}
```