# Crop an image into a rectangle shape when the cropping points are on any shape which has 4 points - IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, crop

In my project, I want to set 4 cropping points manually on an image and crop that image according to set points. For example have a look on below image.

[image]

Like this, all I want is to crop the image according to that path and after cropping it should be a rectangle. This is just like image cropping in CamScanner IOS application. If anyone have any idea how to do this any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35611207/2976878) might be useful - although mapping the result into a rectangle is much more tricky.

Comment: I will try your solution asap. Thanks @originaluser2

Comment: @originaluser2 Cropping is done. The thing i cannot get through is showing the cropped thing as a rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

Here are found very nice github project that have same funtionality what you want but this is in Objective-C might be you can convert this code in to swift check the link following:

https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView

It's output is:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just made one Demo in Swift using **JBCroppableView** Objective-C class implements in Swift. Download from the following and use as per your requirement.

https://github.com/nitingohel/NGCropview

The Combination of Swift + Objective-C

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I need that cropped shape to be mapped into a rectangle. Is it possible with this one??

Comment: you need to understand the logic its blast and apply as par your requerement.

Comment: Okay I'll try. Thanks BTW  :)

Comment: will make a demo and let you know if anythings working :D

Comment: hi check my update answer i made a swift demo using objective-C file

Comment: Thanks bro. Cropping part is okay. Still stuck at the mapping the cropped shape into a rectangle. Thanks for your effort anyway (Y)

Comment: Actually what I wanted is perspective correction. I got it done using CoreImage filter called CIPerspectiveCorrection.

Comment: Nice example, but this library actually not cropping the image just drawing  the area that remains out of corners to white. Do someone know how to crop image with trapezoid shapes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need geometric_transformations.

If you plan to use opencv,  here is a good example:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/

Comment: Yaa, actually what I wanted is perspective correction. I got it done using CoreImage filter called CIPerspectiveCorrection. Thanks for helping friend.

Comment: You are welcome.  Yes, CIPerspectiveCorrection is a good choose for iOS.