# Cropping by any kind of quadrangle

Tags: swift, swift2

I need a cropping system by which I can make any kind of quadrangle rect and can crop by this rect. I search a lot but get nothing about this. I have got rectangle and square rect cropping documentation. Any kind of documentation link, function, project or suggestions will be helpful to me. Here I give an image to clear understand about what I am asking...

I want to crop like this....

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqTXm.png]

Comment: This looks very similar to the problem that was described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608928/crop-image-enclosed-in-a-4-sided-not-rectangle-polygon).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crop image enclosed in a 4 sided (not rectangle) polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608928/crop-image-enclosed-in-a-4-sided-not-rectangle-polygon)